# Type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <div />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-loading-skeleton

I have been trying to implement React skeleton and I have received this error message:

```
type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <div />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?
```

Except for  part, everything worked without any problem.

I have tried followings.

1. Checked there is no wrong spelling
2. mistakes in import and export
3. Replacing  and string, "loading..." and "loading..." displayed while the app is being loaded.

Please help me.

The followings are my codes

**Weather.js**:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import WeatherInfo from "./WeatherInfo";
import WeatherForecast from "./WeatherForecast";
import "./Weather.css";
import axios from "axios";
import "react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css";
import SkeletonLoading from "./skeletons/SkeletonLoading";

export default function Weather(props) {
  const [city, setCity] = useState(props.defaultCity);
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({ ready: false });

  function showWeather(response) {
    setWeather({
      ready: true,
      coordinates: response.data.coord,
      city: response.data.name,
     
    });
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    search();
  }

  function updateCity(event) {
    setCity(event.target.value);
  }
  function search() {
    let apiKey = ``;
    let units = "metric";
    let apiUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}&units=${units}`;
    axios.get(apiUrl).then(showWeather);
  }

  if (weather.ready) {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            className="input-window"
            type="search"
            onChange={updateCity}
          />
          <input className="search-button" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
        <WeatherInfo data={weather} />
        <hr />
        <WeatherForecast coordinates={weather.coordinates} />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    search();
    <SkeletonLoading />;
  }
}
```

**SkeletonLoading.js**:

```
import Skeleton from "react-loading-skeleton";
import "./SkeletonLoading.css";

const SkeletonLoading = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="skeleton-one">
        <Skeleton count={1} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SkeletonLoading();
```

Comment: Well, the error message is actually clear on what's going wrong - you exported a literal (result of running SkeletonLoading) instead of SkeletonLoading component itself.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation,  raina77ow! I was not sure what the error message was about and could not specify what makes SkeletonLoading JSX literal. Now problem's solved and skeleton is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not execute `SkeletonLoading` component when exporting.

Replace the last line of `SkeletonLoading.js` with `export default SkeletonLoading;`

If you execute the component, basically it will export the return value of the function / component. In this case a JSX literal.

Comment: Thanks for clear answer and detailed explanation, Darth Apprentice. Now problem's solved and skeleton is working!